# Convexity of a norm ball without a boundary point

Tags: euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces, convex-geometry

Let $B(r):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \| x\| \leq r\}$ be a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $p\in\partial B(r)$. I want to show that $B(r)\setminus \{p\}$ is convex only using the definition of convexity (i.e. for any two points in the set, the whole segment connecting the two points lies also in the set).

My attempt: Let $x,y\in B(r)\setminus\{p\}$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$. As balls are convex, we have that $(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y\in B(r)$. I then want to show $(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y\neq p$. Assume the contrary, i.e. $(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y = p$.

We can then distinguish three cases: If $\lambda = 0$, we have $x = p$, a contradiction to $x\in B(r)\setminus \{p\}$. If $\lambda = 1$, we have $y=p$ which is a contradiction to $y\in B(r)\setminus\{p\}$. In the last case, let $0 < \lambda < 1$. We then estimate
\begin{equation}
r = \|p\| = \|(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y\| \leq (1-\lambda) \|x\| + \lambda \|y\|< \|x\| + \|y\|.
\end{equation}
Can anyone help me to obtain a contradiction here?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.
So far you have $$r = \|(1-\lambda) x + \lambda y\| \overset{(i)}{\le} (1-\lambda) \|x\| + \lambda \|y\| \overset{(ii)}{\le} (1-\lambda) r + \lambda r = r.$$

To obtain a contradiction, we show that either (i) or (ii) must be a strict inequality.

(ii) attains equality if and only if $\|x\|=\|y\|=r$. If this fails to hold, then (ii) is a strict inequality and we are done.

Thus, to handle the remaining case, assume $\|x\|=\|y\|=r$ and assume (i) is an equality. We will show a contradiction.

In Euclidean space, the triangle inequality (i) attains equality if and only if $x$ and $y$ are parallel (specifically, when $x \cdot y = \|x\| \|y\|$, see the application of Cauchy-Schwarz in the proof of the triangle inequality). But since $\|x\|=\|y\|$ this requires that $x=y$. But then $p=(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y = x$ which contradicts $x \in B \setminus \{p\}$.

Comment: Thank you. How does (ii) being an equality imply $\|x\| = \|y\| = r$? I guess that $\lambda$ has a fixed value here.

Comment: You're already given that $\|x\| \le r$ and $\|y\| \le r$. If $\|x\| < r$ then (ii) becomes a strict inequality. And yes I am considering $\lambda$ fixed. @physicist23